# Call external javascript function frm JSP

Tags: java, javascript, jsp

I'm brand new to the javascript. I'm trying to call a javaScript function from my jsp.Its not working. I was trying to debug it through bugzila. It saying "No Javascript on this page"

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1" %>

   <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4     /loose.dtd">
    <html>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="ajaxs.js"></script>
      <head>
         <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">

      </head>
      <body>
    <%
        out.println("Bismillahir Rahmanir Rahim");
    %>

    <jsp:useBean id="numBean" class="beans.NumberBean">
        <jsp:setProperty name="numBean" property="*" />
    </jsp:useBean>

    <form action="index.jsp" method="post">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Enter Integers:</td>
                <td><input type="text" id="inputString" name="inputString" 
                value="<jsp:getProperty name="numBean"    property="inputString" />" 
                /> </td>
                <td>(Use semi-colon to separate number)</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>M - number of largest element to find.:</td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" id="nthHighest" name="nthHighest" 
                            value="<jsp:getProperty name="numBean" property="nthHighest" />" /> 
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
      <input type="submit" value="Identify" onclick="ajaxFunction()" />
      <div id="result"></div>



    </form>
         </body>
      </html>
```

I'm trying to call "ajaxFunction()" on onclick event.
I included js file as following at the top:
    `<script type="text/javascript" src="ajaxs.js"></script>`
can u pls help me to identify what I'm doing wrong here...

Thanks in advance

Comment: What's the URL displayed in your browser address bar when looking at the page generated by this JSP? And where is the ajaxs.js file relative to this URL? Do you have any error in the Firefox console?

Comment: Your ajaxs.js may be in not in the path mentioned here. Try using some HTTP monitoring tool to check if ajaxs.js is actually downloaded or not.

Answer (score 0):

Try with including script tag with "src="ajaxs.js" (your current script that including "src="ajaxs.js") within head tag.The contents within head tag load at the loading page .

thanks....